# myEclipse namedParameterJDBCTemplate access weblogic datasource

Tags: java, weblogic, datasource, jdbctemplate, myeclipse

In weblogic 10.3.6 server, I have defined the as400 datasource and now I am using myEclipse with java spring framework to develop program to access as400 db by using namedParameterjdbctemplate. I have the sql for as400 select statement. I have below xml code defined in applicationContext.xml in my project. Is there a way to use jdbcParameterNamedTemplate to function as I know jdbcTemplate need to have datasource which will have connection string or password and I not want to enter these values in code but still use weblogic datasource? Is there any example??

```
<beans>
  <bean id="AS400UATJdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
  <property name="jndiName" value="AS400UAT"/>
  <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"/>
  <property name="cache" value="true"/>
  <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
  </bean>

<bean id="getCreditCardByAccountsNumeStoredProcedure" class="com.as400function.GetAccountsByTypeStoredProcedure" singleton="false">
  <constructor-arg>
  <ref bean="AS400UATJdbcTemplate"/>
  </constructor-arg>
  </bean>


  <bean id="AddSingleWithCreditCard" class="com.as400function.AddSingleWithCreditCard" singleton="false">
        <constructor-arg>
            <ref bean="AS400UATJdbcTemplate"/>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: It solved with below answer

Answer (score 0):

I have amended the applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="AS400ForOct" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="AS400UAT"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="getCreditCardByAccountsNumeStoredProcedure" class="com.aeon.awip.membersite.as400function.GetCreditCardByAccountsNumeStoredProcedure" singleton="false">
          <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="AS400ForOct" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Amended the Class file of constructor:

```
public class GetCreditCardByAccountsNumeStoredProcedure extends JdbcDaoSupport{
    public GetOctopusCreditCardByAccountsNumeStoredProcedure (DataSource datasource){
        setDataSource(datasource);
    }
    public GetOctopusCreditCardByAccountsNumeStoredProcedure() {
        super();
    }
.......
}
```

Add below code to call

```
ApplicationContext ctx = ServiceLocator.getApplicationContext();
            getCreditCardByAccountsNumeStoredProcedure = (GetCreditCardByAccountsNumeStoredProcedure)ctx.getBean("getCreditCardByAccountsNumeStoredProcedure");
```